# Translate *Required Fields - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, third-party-module, translate

We have an issue that we are not able to translate "*Required Field" and "This is a Required field"

I also notice that the previous developer have put the Norwegian Language pack under /vendor/magento2translations. I would like to think it should be under app/i18n/magento2translations (create this path ofc.

The owner told me they have used translateline to translate everything on the web page, as in manually. Shouldn't the translate pack do this for them? except if there is any specific translation? We also have problems where we are able to translate via translateline but will not save after we put the site back to production mode.

Another question, do i need to set the i18n/no/NO on every module i have, or have does this work?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The translations in Magento can be done in two ways. One is the use of i8n folder in the theme and another one is the use of i8n folder in the module. You should use the i8n folder in the module when you have to translate the strings that is specific to that module. There is no rule that specifies that you should do it this way, but it is known to be a good practice. You can also use the theme's i8n folder and place the required csv file so that all the translations are in a single place.

The translations should be put in one of the two following paths :

- app/code/Vendor/Module/i8n/***.csv
- app/design/area/Vendor/theme/i8n/***.csv

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

In the excel file i put in one of the modules i have where there is a en_us.csv file from before. I don't need to replace that file do i? and do i need to have it is in this format?:
ENG - NOR - Module path

Comment: Hi, I do not understand the reply. If there is already an en_US.csv, then you can add your Norwegian language translation by creating a file named no_NO.csv and place the translations in there.

Comment: Perfect, now i understand what you mean. :) cheers.

Comment: I manage to translate *This is a required field but not *Required fields... any suggestions`?

Comment: Please refer this file for translations - https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_no_no/blob/master/no_NO.csv. Hope it helps.

Comment: I h ave now tried out different stuff and nothing seams to translate. the link you are referring to I do allready have and is for some reason in this path: mymagentopath/vendor/magento2Translation. (this was the previous developer who put it there. Another thing i have noticed is that when i do php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy i have nb_NO and en_US at the end of that command. And i can also see Norwegian based modules we have installed have a CSV file cal nb_NO.csv under the i18n folder. 

Is there something wrong since I'm not able to translate "Requested Fields? Please help